# Unix sort: inconsistent between 2 files

Tags: sorting, unix

```
[1.txt]
Sample10_1.fq.gz
Sample11_1.fq.gz
Sample12_1.fq.gz
Sample1_1.fq.gz
Sample13_1.fq.gz

[2.txt]
Sample10_2.fq.gz
Sample11_2.fq.gz
Sample12_2.fq.gz
Sample1_2.fq.gz
Sample13_2.fq.gz
```

As you can see, the only difference is the digit after the "_".

Anyway, here are the results of sort:

```
[sort 1.txt]
Sample10_2.fq.gz
Sample11_2.fq.gz
Sample12_2.fq.gz
Sample1_2.fq.gz
Sample13_2.fq.gz

[sort 2.txt]
Sample10_1.fq.gz
Sample11_1.fq.gz
Sample1_1.fq.gz
Sample12_1.fq.gz
Sample13_1.fq.gz
```

Discrepancy: "Sample1_" is sorted between "Sample12" and "Sample13" in 1.txt, but it's between "Sample11" and "Sample12" in 2.txt.

Am I doing something wrong to make this inconsistency happen?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort -V`

```
cat 1.txt | sort -V
Sample1_1.fq.gz
Sample10_1.fq.gz
Sample11_1.fq.gz
Sample12_1.fq.gz
Sample13_1.fq.gz
```

Comment: thanks, but `sort -n` produces the same order.  The result doesn't make sense to me.  In both files, the characters to be sorted at the 8th position of each line are (\_,0,1,2,3), yet "\_" is sorted between 1 and 2 in the first file, but 2 and 3 in the 2nd file.  It looks as though `sort` is considering the character _after_ the current position, which seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Oops. `-n`, `-g`, `-h` and friends treat the whole string as a number. `-V` treats it as a "version string", which is what you want.